# Get a property of an enum based on another property

Tags: java, enums

If I have this enum

```
public static enum Motorcycle {
    YAMAHA("Y", "commons.blue"), BMW("B", "commons.red"), HONDA("H", "commons.yellow"), KAWASAKI("K", "commons.green");

    private String abbreviation;
    private String color;

    SampleStatus(String abbreviation, String color) {
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getAbbreviation() {
        return abbreviation;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

How can I get the color if I have the abbreviation?

E.g.:

String brand = "Y";

How can I get the corresponding color ("commons.blue")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main method for that :

```
  public static void main(String... s){
    for(Motorcycle m : Motorcycle.values()){
        if(m.getAbbreviation().equals("Y")){
            System.out.println(m.getColor());
            break;
        }
    }
  }
```

EDIT use this:

```
 public static String getColorByAbbreviation(String abbreviation){
    for(Motorcycle m : Motorcycle.values()){
        if(m.getAbbreviation().equals(abbreviation)){
            return m.getColor();
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

You can call it by `Motorcycle.getColorByAbbreviation("B")`

Comment: No, you must to loop elements

Comment: If I put this method into my enum how can I access it?

Comment: Insert method(getColorByAbbreviation) to enum and use it as static method

Comment: Look at my answer. it provides a cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

you would have yo create a method in your enum that loops through your elements until it fines it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to iterate over `values()` until you find the right enum and then return its color.

Answer (score 0):

Setup your enums like this:

```
public static enum Motorcycle {
      YAMAHA("Y", "commons.blue"), BMW("B", "commons.red"), HONDA("H", "commons.yellow"), KAWASAKI("K", "commons.green");

    private String abbreviation;
    private String color;

    private static Map<String, Motorcycle> motorcyclesByAbbr = new HashMap<String, Motorcycle>();

    static {
         for (Motorcycle m : Motorcycle.values()) {
             motorcyclesByAbbr.put(m.getAbbreviation(), m);
         }
    }
    SampleStatus(String abbreviation, String color) {
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getAbbreviation() {
        return abbreviation;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public static Motorcycle getByAbbreviation(String abbr) {
        return motorcyclesByAbbr.get(abbr);
    }
}
```